# How can I make IDA disassemble in NASM-like syntax instead of MASM-like syntax?

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers, nasm

I'm new to reverse engineering, assembly and IDA and I'm learning NASM. Whenever I load an executable (a PE file or an ELF) IDA disassembles it using a MASM-like syntax (it looks to me that it does) and I think NASM is better so I'm sticking to NASM but IDA doesn't help me with that. So:
How can I make it disassemble in a NASM-like syntax?
Also because there are major differences between MASM and NASM like using the square brackets differs in both (like: mov eax, [var]), How do I know what IDA exactly uses if it is not using MASM?

Any understanding and help is highly appreciated as I do not know how to word most of things in this regard and don't understand many concepts.